# if else react one-liner

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change the state of a `Nav.Toggle` in `react-bootstrap`. c

Currently, I have got it to open when clicked but I would like it to close i.e. `this.setState({ expanded: false})` when clicked if the current state is `"expanded"`.

My `onClick` handler looks as such:

```
onClick={() => (this.state.expanded ? false : this.setState({ expanded: "expanded" }))}
```

How do I make it say `else if this.state.expanded ? "expanded" : this.setState({ expanded: false })`?

I assume I should move this logic above the `render` method so bonus points if you can show me how to do it under this line as well:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            expanded: false
        };
    }

handleNavToggle => ???
```

Thanks!

Comment: so you want a function to make nav expand or shrink ?

Comment: yeah, but I am learning so I would like to know both full function and one-liner if possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if it's a boolean initially, you can just put exclamation mark in front of it.

```
onClick={() => this.setState(() => ({expanded: !this.state.expanded}))}
```

this way it will become true or false back and forth.

Edit: Don't forget to return as an object so you need open to normal paranthesis before curly braces.

Comment: So I got a weird error with this one but if you remove `this.state` from the first one then it works: `onClick={() => this.setState(() => ({expanded : !this.state.expanded}))}`.. If you update your answer I will mark as accepted. Also, would you mind showing how to do this below the contructor if I want to move the function up there?

Comment: @DavidAlford ah yes you're right. It's been a while since I dont write class components, I also suggest you to use functional ones. It's way easier with React Hooks.

Answer (score 2):

`setState` has a [second form](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) you can use if you want the state to depend on the previous state.

I suppose this is something like what you're after:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    expanded: false
  };
}

toggleExpanded = () => {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    expanded: !prevState.expanded ? 'expanded' : false
  }));
};

render() {
  return (
    <Nav.Toggle
      onClick={this.toggleExpanded}
    />
  );
}
```

However, I'd recommend you to stick to one type. Either boolean or string. With a boolean, the setState callback would simply be as `(prevState) => ({ expanded: !prevState.expanded })`

Comment: Yes! That looks much cleaner to me! Thank you!

Comment: I couldn't put my finger on why I liked this form better at first but then I realized it is becuase I can resuse `this.toggleExpanded` in other places. eg. the inner nav items. Good to know both forms though!

Comment: Yes. Another benefit is that when you provide an anonymous callback as prop, it will be created each time your component is rendered, which will trigger the child component to be re-rendered. With a method passed as the prop, you will re-use it in order to not trigger a re-render. To regard stuff like that is in it's essence premature optimization, but I think it looks cleaner if the JSX declarations and the render method in general are not filled with logic.

Best of luck on your journey of learning React. :)

Comment: Oh sheesh thats a lot! I will have to look into it all. Thanks!